# Exact Differential: Integrating Factor in Higher Dimensions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential, integrating-factor

In two dimensions, we can turn every inexact differential $f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy$ into an exact version by multiplying both functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ by an additional function $I(z)$, i.e. $I(z) f(x,y) dx + I(z) g(x,y) dy = 0$, where $z = xy$. Then, the condition that the cross-derivatives should be the same, i.e.

$$f_y(x,y) I(z) + x I'(z) f(x,y) = g_x(x,y) I(z) + y I'(z) g(x,y),$$

lead to a differential equation for $I$ and therewith to the solution.

Is this trick of multiplying the inexact differential by an additional function also possible in higher dimension, i.e. for $n$ variables? In other words, is there a possibility to make $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x) dx_i$ exact, where $a_i(x)$ are arbitrary $C^1$-functions? An idea would be

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x) \sum_{k=1}^n I_{ik}(x_i x_k) dx_i$$

to account for the cross-derivatives. Is this solveable for $I_{ik}$ or are there other approaches? Does anybody has experiences therefore? Thanks already.

Comment: I don't know. As a comment however, exact differential equations and conservative vector fields/potential functions are basically the same mathematics I think. I haven't heard of a conservative vector field with 4 or more components? I've heard of two 2-variable functions being derivable from a single potential function, and three 3-variable functions being derivable from a single potential function. To get $n$, $n$-variable functions from a single potential function maybe. You'd probably need a lot of mixing and matching of partial derivatives

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact differential should be of variable size. I read meanwhile something about the Pfaffian problem which could be related to the problem: https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.1877.issue-82/crll.1877.82.230/crll.1877.82.230.xml
However, I do not have a final answer, hoping this changes in the near future.